# Help with wiring a computer PWM fan to DC voltage

Tags: electrical, wiring, fans, soldering

I've recently purchased a "fume extractor" from China which is basically a filter with a pc fan behind it. The Fan pre-installed isn't really doing much of anything and I would like to replace it with a powerful PC fan that I have lying around.

Pictures can be found here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFFC7.jpg

I have a multimeter lying around but am not really proficient with it. The diagrams that I can find on the web for PWM fans state that Black should be ground and yellow should be 12v. The pre installed fan only sported 2 wires instead of the 4 of mine and thus isn't anything to go by.

Can I just hook up the ground / 12v wire to the corresponding wires from the "fume extractor" or is there anything else I should be aware of?

Comment: Welcome. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how this site operates.

Comment: The one picture shows a AC voltage of 90 - 265V.   Is that the fan you want to hook up to 12V DC? I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can just hook up the fan to +12V  (yellow) and Ground (black)  and ignore the control lines of the fan. They are for fan speed control to reduce noise in a computer. If they are not connected, fan runs always at full speed.

Comment: And for details on how computer fans are controlled there is good description in [this thread](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/fan-speed-control-how-to-2-pin-vs-3-pin-vs-4-pin.2200004/).

Answer (score 0):

The additional wires are probably speed reporting and/or variable speed control. They can likely be ignored.

[More on that](https://superuser.com/a/1126155/155426)

You'll want to be sure that your fan isn't a 5v unit, though.

Comment: According to the specs it is 0.1A, 1.2W, DC12V